# Mimic delegation of control wizard with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, delegation

I want to delegate control of the `TestUsers` organizational unit to a user `NickA` and give the following permissions to it:

1. `Create, delete, and manage user accounts`
2. `Reset user passwords and force password change at next logon`
3. `Read all user information`
4. `Create, delete and manage groups`
5. `Modify the membership of a group`

The only method that I found is the following, but I cannot find the correct permissions to assign:

```
$acc  = Get-ADUser NickA
$sid  = new-object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $acc.SID
$guid = new-object Guid bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2 
$ou   = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity TestUsers
$acl  = Get-ACL -Path "AD:$($ou.DistinguishedName)"
$acl.AddAccessRule($(new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $sid,"CreateChild,DeleteChild","Allow",$guid))
Set-ACL -ACLObject $acl -Path "AD:$($ou.DistinguishedName)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it using PowerShell. Thanks to the following TechNet posts [Exchange 2007 GUID Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee331014(v=EXCHG.80).aspx) and [Update ACL Skeleton](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Update-ACL-Skeleton-2afcfc8f) I was able to delegate control of the TestUsers organizational unit to a user NickA and give the permissions that I originally posted.

```
$OU   = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity "OU=TestUsers,DC=contoso,DC=private"
$SID  = new-object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $(Get-ADUser "NickA").SID
$GUIDUserOBJ  = new-object Guid bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
$GUIDGroupOBJ = new-object Guid bf967a9c-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
$GUIDNull     = new-object Guid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 

$ACL  = Get-ACL -Path "AD:$($OU.DistinguishedName)"

#Create a hashtable to store the GUID value of each schema class and attribute
$ADRootDSE = Get-ADRootDSE
$GUIDMap = @{}
Get-ADObject -SearchBase ($ADRootDSE.SchemaNamingContext) -LDAPFilter "(schemaidguid=*)" -Properties lDAPDisplayName,schemaIDGUID | % {$GUIDMap[$_.lDAPDisplayName]=[System.GUID]$_.schemaIDGUID}

$ACL.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $SID,"CreateChild,DeleteChild","Allow",$GUIDUserOBJ,"ALL"))
$ACL.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $SID,"GenericAll","Allow",$GUIDNull,"Descendents",$GUIDMap["user"]))
$ACL.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $SID,"CreateChild,DeleteChild","Allow",$GUIDGroupOBJ,"ALL"))
$ACL.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $SID,"GenericAll","Allow",$GUIDNull,"Descendents",$GUIDMap["group"]))

Set-ACL -ACLObject $ACL -Path "AD:$($OU.DistinguishedName)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tackled ACL building with PowerShell yet, but this can be done with the old DSACLS command that has been part of RSAT and the Support Tools since Windows Server 2003.

```
dsacls "OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=com" /I:S /G "domain\user:CA;Reset Password";user
```

Put the DN of the delegated OU in between the quotes and put the user after the /G (grant) parameter. The `/I:S` parameter tells the ACE to inherit for child objects only, and the `CA` parameter stands for Control Access.

More on the syntax can be found on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771151(v=ws.11).aspx) or other sites. If you need to use PowerShell, check out the [Update ACL Active Directory Provider documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251753.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I was able to do it using PowerShell, please see below.